# Is there a way to limit heap space when running a single JUnit test?

Tags: java, junit

I have some code that needs to be able to run on systems with limited memory (i.e., 1750MB), and I have a JUnit test specifically for that code. However, my Jenkins integration server that runs the unit tests runs with a heap space set to 4GB.

On my development workstation in Eclipse, I can manually run the unit test with a VM argument of `-Xmx1750m`.

Is there some annotation that I can add to an individual JUnit test case that would force the test to run with the above VM argument (without affecting other unit tests)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JUnit Test is nothing more than a Java class that runs inside the JVM. Thus, it will be difficult to specify these constraints for just a single unit test. In the end, you would have to configure the JVM itself.

To achive this, you can use a seperate configuration for your tests, here demonstrated with Maven. First, you can make use of the surefire-plugins `argLine` configuration property to configure the environment. Next, limit the class to be tested with the `include` configuration, as described [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
        <includes>
            <include>...</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then, use a custom profile that is probably triggered by a property active on your build server.

```
<profile>
    <id>low-memory-tests</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>...</name>
        </property>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

**Notes:**

- Even if you run only one single unit test in this profile, you still cannot guarantee that just the test can *consume* 2048m of heap space, but the whole application. But i suppose that this would be a good bet.
- Even if you are not using Maven, other build tools should have a similar way to apply above configuration, you get the idea.